# Clear JTable after printing the receipt and comes back when I order again

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When I click the receipt button it asks the user if I would like to order again, I've cleared already the table but when I order a new product again the items I've ordered first on the first receipt goes back to the table..

```
public void refTable() {

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{},
            new String[]{
                "Menu", "Price", "Quantity", "Total"
            }
    ) {
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
            false, false, false, false
        };

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit[columnIndex];
        }
    });
    try {

        double total = 0;
        for (MenuModel menumodel : controller1.getMenulist()) {
            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
            al.add(menumodel.getItemName());
            al.add(formatter.format(menumodel.getPrice()));
            al.add((int) menumodel.getQuantity() + "");
            al.add(formatter.format(menumodel.getTotal()));
            total = total + menumodel.getTotal();

            tableModel.addRow(al.toArray());
        }
        double tax = 0.12;
        JLabel_subTotal.setText(formatter.format(total));
        JLabel_Tax.setText(formatter.format(total * tax));
        JLabel_Total.setText(formatter.format((total * tax) + total));
        JTableOrderReceived.setModel(tableModel);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("sad");
    }
}

private void JTableMenuOrderMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    int quanti = 0;
    int row = JTableMenuOrder.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
    if (row >= 0 && row < JTableMenuOrder.getRowCount()) {
        JTableMenuOrder.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
    } else {
        JTableMenuOrder.clearSelection();
    }
    int rowindex = JTableMenuOrder.getSelectedRow();
    if (rowindex < 0) {
        return;
    }

    String quantity = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, controller.getMenulist().get(rowindex).getItemName() + "\n" + "Number of Quantity :");
    selectedProduct = controller.getMenulist().get(rowindex);
    MenuModel mouseSelected = new MenuModel();
    MenuModel menumodel = controller1.search(selectedProduct.getItemName());
    try {
        if (menumodel != null) {
            selectedProduct = controller1.search(selectedProduct.getItemName());
            if (quanti > 0) {
                double temp = menumodel.getQuantity();
                quanti += temp;
                controller1.removeMenu(selectedProduct);
                refTable();
                mouseSelected.setItemName(selectedProduct.getItemName());
                mouseSelected.setPrice(selectedProduct.getPrice());
                mouseSelected.setQuantity(quanti);
                mouseSelected.setTotal(quanti * selectedProduct.getPrice());
                controller1.addMenu(mouseSelected);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error");
            }
        } else {
            if (quanti > 0) {
                mouseSelected.setItemName(selectedProduct.getItemName());
                mouseSelected.setPrice(selectedProduct.getPrice());
                mouseSelected.setQuantity(quanti);
                mouseSelected.setTotal(quanti * selectedProduct.getPrice());
                controller1.addMenu(mouseSelected);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cannot add item: " + selectedProduct.getItemName() + "\nYou must enter quantity", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        refTable();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Cannot add item: " + selectedProduct.getItemName() + "\nQuantity must be greater than zero!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}                                             

private void JTableOrderReceivedMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                  
    int row = JTableOrderReceived.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
    if (row >= 0 && row < JTableOrderReceived.getRowCount()) {
        JTableOrderReceived.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);

    } else {
        JTableOrderReceived.clearSelection();
    }
    int rowindex = JTableOrderReceived.getSelectedRow();
    if (rowindex < 0) {
        return;
    }
    selectedProduct = controller.getMenulist().get(rowindex);
    if (evt.isPopupTrigger()) {
        Delete.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());
    }
}                                                 

  //This is the reciept button action----
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("Customer name: " + menubill.getCustomerName() + "\n");
    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to order again?", "EAT N' RUN", JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) JTableOrderReceived.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    JTextField_customerName.setText("");
}
```

I guess the problem is with this code

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) JTableOrderReceived.getModel();
model.setRowCount(0);
```

It just temporarily clears the orders I've received but it comes back when I order a product again in the menu.. Maybe someone can help on how to? or what's wrong on it on why it comes back..

Comment: First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and follow the standards. Most of your variable are correct. Be consistent!!! 1) How do you know the setRowCount(0) statement is executed? If it is then the TableModel will be empty. If data still appears in the JTable, then that means you either have two instances of the jTable or the TableModel and you are setting the row count of the wrong model.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table(s).